# Impersonate issue with remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I inherited a project that I was asked to look at. It's an ASP.NET website that is deployed on a clients intranet server. They gave me VPN access and the source code. They are using Active Directory for authentication.

So here's my setup: Code running locally, connected to their db on their db server.

In the web.config I see that authentication mode=Windows and identity impersonate is true. However, when I run the project I get this error:

> Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in
>   the config file.  Error from the operating system 'The security
>   database on the server does not have a computer account for this
>   workstation trust relationship.

The username for the identity line (web.config) is a service account. All this runs fine in production. Any ideas as to why this app is not authenticating? Thanks!

Comment: if you are using`AD for authentication, I am assuming that this site also has a login screen.. the error is probably seeing the remote machines name as not being in AD personally I would not use impersonation I would authenticate off of the users username and Domain and you can also use `PrincipalContext` along with very little AD code to validate the password.. but `PrincipalContext` in my opinion is all you need if they are in the domain.. only thing is if they are outside of the `DMZ` then you would need to have a different form of authentication..

Comment: Are you saying that my dev machine name needs to be setup in their AD? Also, many of the users are working remotely, connecting to the website from hotels, etc... So, would you just use standard Forms authentication then?

Comment: you would need to have `VPN` setup get with an experienced `network admin` you are setting yourself up for lots of issues in my opinion doing it this way.. and if your Dev machine is not setup in the network then I would say that this is a flawed architecture as well

Comment: Thanks! They did give me vpn access. As I mentioned I just inherited this project and the former developer was working fine. Do you think its just that my dev box needs proper permissions? The client just wants me to fix a bug, not redesign how security is working (at least right now), so I'd like to just get this working quickly. Thanks so much for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If your dev machine is not joined to their domain, then it *might* not work. But maybe it's possible.

As a start, try disabling Kerberos and forcing NTLM using this in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
        <providers>
          <clear />
          <add value="NTLM" />
        </providers>
      </windowsAuthentication>
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

If you are hosting locally in IIS, then you can do the same in IIS Manager. Select the site -> Authentication -> Right click Windows Authentication -> Providers -> Remove 'Negotiate' from the list, leaving only NTLM.